# Regex match but exclude character from capture group

Tags: regex

I have the following regex:-

```
^(?:\[ [^\]]+ \]) ([\-\£]{1,2}[0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9]?)?
```

And the following text:-

```
John Doe
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Blah blah
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
[ √ ] £3.00 Red
[ √ ] £2.00 Blue
[ √ ] £55.55 Yellow
[ √ ] -£41.75 PAYMENT
[ √ ] £5.00 Green
[ √R ] £10.00 Pink
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Belugh
+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
Blah blah
Blah
```

The regex works ok and matches:-

```
£3.00
£2.00
£55.55
-£41.75
£5.00
£10.00
```

What I want to do though is to have the regex match the '£' but not return it in the capturing group.

So the results would be like this:-

```
3.00
2.00
55.55
-41.75
5.00
10.00
```

The important bit is the '-' character which should remain, but occurs before the '£' character.

Theres a fiddle [here](http://regexr.com/39cjp)

Comment: That's not possible within the regex, use your environments capabilities to go through the matches and "clean up" anything you don't want. Regexes might help with the cleaning up, but I don't think you can do this with 1 regex.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Best you can do is this:

```
^(?:\[ [^\]]+ \]) (-?)[\£]([0-9]+\.[0-9][0-9]?)?
```

And then extract group 1 and group 2 from the matches and append them in the language/environment you're working in.

[Demo](http://regex101.com/r/bE9wI5/1)

Comment: I actually prefer debuggex.com, particularly when doing more complicated stuff. But regex101 has some nice features too :)

Answer (score 0):

I did this by including the "£" in the capture group and then simply replacing that symbol with "nothing" from the matched results in the language I'm working in.